# Why we should add @Stateless to an Entity in a Maven Project?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

When I created my first empty `Entreprise Application` with `Maven`, I had this error, even when I created an `Entity`:

```
    Invalid ejb jar it contains zero ejb
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.
```

Entity.java:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

Then I found that the solution to this issue is to add `@Stateless` to the `Entity Class:
package test;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Stateless
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

It works fine, but now I want to know why I had to add this annotation to the `Entity` to work fine ?

The config details are:

- Netbeans 8.1
- Glassfish 4.1.1
- pgAdmin III
- Maven 3.5

The EAR module has the maven-ear-plugin configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does your "Enterprise Application" contain just the one WAR file?

Comment: @SteveC  Yes it does

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the presence of that @Stateless annotation will cause weird stuff to happen at runtime, so you should remove that.

As your resulting jar contains zero EJBs then it's packaging type should be changed from `ejb` to `jar`.

Make sure that your maven-ear-plugin looks something like:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>7</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <!-- no ejb module -->
                    <webModule>
                       ...
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and your application should deploy properly.

Furthermore, as you're using GlassFish 4.x, you could dispense with the "Enterprise Application" altogether and just put everything in your WAR file which can then be deployed on it's own.

You can even add EJBs to the WAR later if you want.

These days you would only use an EAR when you're working on an ancient monolith. Make your build only as complicated as needed.

Comment: this is my "ear pom file":
 `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BookTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>BookTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>BookTest</name>
  <modules>
    <module>BookTest-ear</module>
    <module>BookTest-web</module>
    <module>BookTest-ejb</module>
  </modules>`

What should  I remove ?

Comment: That is your parent pom, not your BookTest-ear pom.

Comment: excuse me, this is it:
`<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
   
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <version>6</version>
            <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`

Comment: That will probably work fine. You don't need the compiler-plugin at all because this module should not contain any Java source files. You can safely upgrade the version to 7 as well as the plugin version if you want.

Comment: Yes this is should work but it unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Do you have the same problem? Did you change the Maven packaging for the "BookTest-ejb" module (which is not really an EJB module)?

Comment: Yes always the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149483/discussion-between-steve-c-and-mehdi-bouzidi).

Comment: can we do this later ? cause my Company's Security filter doesn't let me acces the chat link

Comment: I get it. 
The pom.xml for BookTest-ejb should **not** contain <packaging>ejb</packaging>.

Comment: Please show me what the generated `application.xml` file looks like. Make sure that your EAR BookTest-ejb dependency has `<type>ejb</type>` removed